# Recurring events in Google Calendar API on Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I have started to use the Google Calendar Api and now I'm ok with the
authetication, get the calendar list, rename the calendars, and add
event with specified time and title to a selected calendar.

I have started to use the model from the [calendar-v2-atom-android-sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/model/?repo=samples&r=6332fc8fc9b72d3dd55b6296ff26d38524b53808) and i figured out
what I have to add to the model for the events because I read [Access event data in Android app on Google Apps APIs](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=3b948784a9502531&hl=en)

But now I have to add a recurring events, after reading 
[CreatingRecurring](http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingRecurring),
I am unclear as to what the content of the `public class
Recurrence {}`.  How is this implemented and how should I define the
`setRecurrence(Recurrence recurr)()` function.

Answer (score 0):

GData 2.0 is both deprecated and not compatible with Android.

I would recommend using the [Google Calendar Api](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#recurring_events). Setting recurrence is explained in the [rfc2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445).

If you're developing for anything above Android API Level 14 (aka ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH 4.0), you can use CalendarContract